# Writing files in HDD becomes slower with the increase in number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a multithreaded env using ExecutorService. All my threads are doing the same thing. 
They are getting the data from DB, preparing the PDF using itext and writing PDF at a location in D drive. 
But I noticed a weird thing. As I am increasing the number of threads, my end-to-end process becomes slower. 
For 1 thread - 4000 pdf generated in 1 hour 
For 2 threads - 3500 pdf generated in 1 hour 
For 3 threads - 3200 pdf generated in 1 hour 
For 4 threads - 3000 pdf generated in 1 hour

Using logger, it became clear that, getting the data from DB is very fast, bottleneck is the PDF writing operation.

Somewhere I read that in windows, writing multiple files at same directory simultaneously becomes slower compared to sequential writing. 
If true, what other logic I can implement to get a higher performance. 
Thank you.

### Environment details

OS - Windows 7 ,32 bit 
RAM - 3 GB 
Processor - Core i3 
JDK - 1.6 
DB - PostgreSql 9.3 
Size of PDF - varies between 500KB and 2 MB

Comment: I think it is because writing pdf file is IO operation and it is blocking, so it became a bottle neck for threads

Comment: maybe have one thread for writing and others for preparing the data.  I wonder if the writer Thread would keep up though.

Comment: I think the problem is, that threading has a scheduling mechanism. Threading is just a kind of parallel working. In reality it is just sequentiell. Maybe if you use more threads it has to reopen the file or just start writing again.

Comment: @MarcelHöll: Not on any modern CPU it isn't. Once you have multiple cores, you can *truly* do more than one thing at a time. But I/O will kill it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to HDD is a IO blocking operation so you will gain nothing by doing to with multithreading. With HDD you will actually experience a slow down. If you switch to SSD, then it's possible that you will not experience a slow down doing a multithreading disk access (or the slow down will be less that with HDD  at least), but there will be no improvement neither.

The situation might be different if you have a RAID, but it depends on the type of the RAID.

To increase performance in your scenario you should split the work you do on the threads in such a way: 
1) Having one IO thread for reading/writing from the disk (or alternatively having one IO thread for reading and another IO thread for writing - for that would even better). 
2) Having a separate thread for calculations. This thread should not do any IO operations on the disk.

The IO threads will simply read data from the disk and pass the data into a queue (let's call it an "input queue"). And then the "calculations thread" picks up the data from the "input queue", processes it, and puts results into another queue (let's call it an "results queue"). The IO thread can then pick the data up from the "results queue" and write that into disk.

Comment: *"...or alternatively having one IO thread for reading and another IO thread for writing - for that would even better..."* No, that still causes thrashing, yanking the heads from place to place.

Answer (score 1):

The HDD can only write to one portion of the disk at a time, so if you have several different threads (or even processes) writing at the same time, the disk has to move its heads all over the place, writing a bit to file A here, a bit to File B there, etc. This is why it's actually *slower* to split this task into threads, you're making the HDD work harder.

If you have any CPU-intensive tasks, they can frequently be multiplexed across a couple of threads to get benefits on any modern CPU, but as soon as you're dealing with a singleton resource like a specific HDD, you're generally better off sticking to a single thread for that aspect of what you're doing.